# Is there a function that is able to cut a sound depending on the volume?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

In Video sequencer,
I would like to have a automatized transformation of my sounds. When i'm doing a video with recorded spitch. I have to cut all the silences . It's a very stupid work and it's take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The VSE can't do detections and auto removing silence like that, but ffmpeg can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411973